# How to create development sharepoint server from backup of a UAT server

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem

I have been tasked to create a new development server to be installed in a server and in a VM. I am not too well informed with how to do this. is it better to install a new sharepoint server or can i do a full farm backup of the uat from the CA?

Answer (score 0):

You can install SharePoint server on a VM, then do a full farm backup from UAT farm, and restore it in your development environment.

About setting up development environment, you can refer to the following article:
[Set up a general development environment for SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/set-up-a-general-development-environment-for-sharepoint)

Answer (score 0):

I would first create the dev farm following a guide like this one:

https://www.petri.com/setup-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-farm-configuration

And then using SQL Server Management Studio I would make backups of the UAT content databates and restore them to the dev SQL server. I would then drop any existing databases attached to the dev Web Applications ( by using Remove-SPContentDatabase); and then attach the restored databases (by using Mount-SPContentDatabase).

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to install SharePoint on the development server. below are quick steps:

1. Install SQL on Dev machine if you want to set up [single-server farm](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33907.sharepoint-server-2016-single-server-installation-configuration.aspx)
2. Before Installing SharePoint you have to install its prerequisites.
3. Then Install SharePoint server, Admin account thru which you are configuring the SP should have the permission **db_owner** permission.
4. Build a Web application then either you can [mount](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/mount-spcontentdatabase?view=sharepoint-ps) DB from the source server to target server or [restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/restore-spsite?view=sharepoint-ps) the backup file to the target server.
5. configure services if required.

Helpful references:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-server-2016-installation-and-setup/

https://www.petri.com/setup-sharepoint-2013-development-environment-farm-configuration

https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/complete-premise-sharepoint-2016-setup-guide-simple-easy-steps-troubleshooting/